# Sonarqube C# scanner exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is not a valid line offset for pointer"

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Using Sonarqube v5.6 on a windows server, c# scanner v5.5.0.479

Seems to pick this up in multiple files, and not always the same files, which is the most concerning.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
16:46:03 INFO: Importing analysis results from E:\Jenkins\workspace\Job Build-UnitTest (PullRequests)\.sonar\output-cs
16:46:05 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:46:05 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
16:46:05 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:46:05 INFO: Total time: 3:36.304s
16:46:05 INFO: Final Memory: 53M/700M
16:46:05 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:46:05 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
16:46:05 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 30 is not a valid line offset for pointer. File [moduleKey=JOB:develop, relative=DataStructures/Interval.cs, basedir=E:\Jenkins\workspace\Job Build-UnitTest (PullRequests)] has 1 character(s) at line 132
16:46:05    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:148)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.checkValid(DefaultInputFile.java:218)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newPointer(DefaultInputFile.java:209)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInputFile.java:239)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.SensorContextUtils.toTextRange(SensorContextUtils.java:41)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.IssuesImporter.importMessage(IssuesImporter.java:54)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.IssuesImporter.importMessage(IssuesImporter.java:31)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.AbstractProtobufImporter.accept(AbstractProtobufImporter.java:49)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.parseProtobuf(AbstractSensor.java:80)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.importResults(AbstractSensor.java:70)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.java:114)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:85)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
16:46:05    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
16:46:05    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:46:05    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
16:46:05    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:46:05    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
16:46:05    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
16:46:05    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
16:46:05 ERROR: 
16:46:05 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
16:46:05 ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the C# plugin. The fix is coming. Until then you can change the encoding of your files to UTF-8.

Comment: I just want to say thank you, we love the tool and all the hard work to get it up to where it is today is greatly appreciated!

That being said, do we have an ETA on the fix? Some of my tribe are losing confidence in the tool because it bombs out. Changing the encoding on 8000000 files isn't an option. Thanks!

Comment: @Mumbles76 No official ETA, it's already in the pipeline (, it will come in the upcoming days).

Comment: I'm having this issue, too. I can't find it in the issue tracker. Do you have a url for it so I can anticipate its progress? :)

Comment: @mo. If you go to update center, update the plugin it's fixed now.

Comment: I'm using [v5.5.1.522](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900) of the C# plugin on Sonar 5.6.4. It has a release date from prior to Tamas' answer, and I don't see an update available for it in the update center. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mo, could you add some details of what you're experiencing? If 5.5.1 didn't fix the issue for you, then you're running into another problem. Probably it's worth starting a new SO question.

Comment: My error is identical, and the line in the file that it's erroring on looks like this: `        /// FieldValue should be passed as either ‘T’ or ‘F’. ’T’ for Checked and ‘F’ for Unchecked.` (note utf-8 quote characters). Before I start a new question, is there a way to verify which version of the plugin it's running at scan time? Does the scanner pull down the plugin to the client?

Comment: @Tamas I asked [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41623172/326110)