# Sonarqube C# v5.5.2 still has “java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is not a valid line offset for pointer”

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

This is related to [Sonarqube C# scanner exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is not a valid line offset for pointer"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41042943/326110)

Using Sonarqube v5.6.4 on a windows server, c# scanner v5.5.2.537.
MSBuild version is: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
I'm just using the non-service mode, `StartSonar.bat` while trying to get it working on this codebase, if that makes any difference.

The `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file in question is UTF-16. You can [view it in an online hex editor](https://hexed.it#base64+lzjb: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).

```
    INFO: Importing analysis results from X:\tfs\Sonar2016\.sonarqube\out\PROJECTNAME\output-cs
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: Total time: 2:49.355s
    INFO: Final Memory: 61M/2305M
    ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 47 is not a valid line offset for pointer. File [moduleKey=no_AfterCompile_NormalBuild:no_AfterCompile_NormalBuild:DB96E47F-8CF8-487B-A19C-69BE6EC13F0F, relative=GlobalSuppressions.cs, basedir=X:\tfs\Sonar2016\PROJECTLOCATION] has 1 character(s) at line 2
            at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:148)
            at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.checkValid(DefaultInputFile.java:218)
            at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newPointer(DefaultInputFile.java:209)
            at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInputFile.java:240)
            at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.SensorContextUtils.toTextRange(SensorContextUtils.java:41)
            at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.HighlightImporter.consumeFor(HighlightImporter.java:51)
            at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.HighlightImporter.consumeFor(HighlightImporter.java:33)
            at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.ProtobufImporter.consume(ProtobufImporter.java:49)
            at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.RawProtobufImporter.accept(RawProtobufImporter.java:43)
            at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.parseProtobuf(AbstractSensor.java:95)
            at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.importResults(AbstractSensor.java:87)
            at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.java:111)
            at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:82)
            at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
            at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
            at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
            at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
            at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
            at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
            at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
            at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
            at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
            at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
            at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
    ERROR:
    ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
    The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
    14:27:41.669  Creating a summary markdown file...
    14:27:41.694  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Comment: I gave this a quick try and I can't repro this on SQ 6.1. I'll have a look later on SQ 5.6.4. Also, can you tell me the exact version of msbuild that you're using?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the Q to include msbuild ver 14.0.25420.1. Also just using `StartSonar.bat`. Doubt that would make a difference though.

Comment: I checked with SQ 5.6.4, and I can't repro the issue either.

Comment: I'm also using the command line start, so that's definitely not the issue. Can you share the full console log of the Scanner for MsBuild end step?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue with SonarQube 5.6.6 LTS, SonarC# 5.8.0.660. The file causing the issue is identified as having encoding UCS-2 LE Format by notepad++ which apparently is something along the lines of UTF-16? Is this related to [this issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-648?jql=project%20%3D%20SONARCS%20AND%20text%20~%20%22utf-8%22)?